# App is crashing after looking for EditText.isEmpty()

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-edittext, kotlin

I don't even understand what's is this and why it doesn't work ok. I have button, which starts new activity. But before it, I check some values, and after clicking on the button - it's crashing .-. I don't know what to do, it doesn't work properly anyway. I'm writing on 
Code:

```
lateinit var string: String
var day: Int = 0
var month: Int = 0
var yearProp: Int = 0
var dayEnd: Int = 0
var monthEnd: Int = 0
var yearEndProp: Int = 0
var priceFrom: Int = 0
var priceTo: Int = 0
companion object {
    lateinit var props: Properties
}

override fun onDateSet(view: DatePickerDialog?, year: Int, monthOfYear: Int, dayOfMonth: Int, yearEnd: Int, monthOfYearEnd: Int, dayOfMonthEnd: Int) {
    day = dayOfMonth
    month = monthOfYear
    yearProp = year
    dayEnd = dayOfMonthEnd
    monthEnd = monthOfYearEnd
    yearEndProp = yearEnd
    button_whats_date.text = getString(R.string.title_from) + ": " + day + "/" + month + "/" + yearProp + " | " + getString(R.string.title_to) + ": " + dayEnd + "/" + monthEnd + "/" + yearEndProp
}    

param_done.setOnClickListener {
        if (input_price_from.getText().toString().matches("".toRegex()) || input_price_to.getText().toString().matches("".toRegex())) {
            priceFrom = 0; priceTo = 999999999
            Log.i("VALUES", "" + priceTo)
            if (Integer.parseInt(input_price_from.text.toString()) > Integer.parseInt(input_price_to.text.toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, getString(R.string.error_change_price), LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                try {
                    props = Properties(string, int, int, int, int, int, int, priceFrom, priceTo)
                    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SearchActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                } catch (e: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, getString(R.string.props_error), LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.i("Hereissometex", "User cannot follow to next activity")
                }
            }
        }
    }


<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_price_from"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:hint="@string/title_from"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_price_to"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:hint="@string/title_to"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/param_done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/done"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And it's just crashing down. If you need something else - just give me a sign. There is how I do check input values:

```
input_price_from.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            priceFrom = Integer.parseInt(input_price_from.text.toString())
        }
    })
    input_price_to.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            priceTo = Integer.parseInt(input_price_to.text.toString())
            Log.i("[TravelMet::INFO]", "InputPrice value changed and parced")
        }
    })   

**EDIT**: Added log.


    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: s.com.s, PID: 1979
                  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:533)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
                      at arsensaruhanyan.com.travelmet.MainActivity$onCreate$5.onClick(MainActivity.kt:110)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11185)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23752)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)

101:
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, getString(R.string.error_change_price), LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: please put logcat,,

Comment: I don't see isEmpty() being used in your code?

Comment: @TreytenCarey sorry, I've changed it (How I said, I tried to solve it in many ways). Now it looks so: input_price_from.getText().toString().matches("".toRegex())

Comment: Like @ABK said, update your question to include the logcat.

Comment: @TreytenCarey I did it right now, sorry. Check it out.

Comment: @ABK done. Check it out.

Comment: Great, the problem was very clear after adding your log :)

Comment: @TreytenCarey is something wrong?

Comment: Yes, view the answers you were given on this post.

Comment: -1. The comments are used to ask for more information, I.E your logcat. Don't ask if something is wrong after you have several answers on your post, then I won't need to reassure you to look at them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gosh, it's terrible to understand, but I fixed it just by using this condition:

```
if (priceFrom > priceTo)
```

And, I think no: price_from isn't too important, because price_to is checking out by the same way.

Anyway, thanks to all for help

Answer (score 0):

I guess the exception is pretty clear

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

change here and check the text is not empty and is of greater length

check if the text is not empty

```
try{
    if(input_price_from.text.toString().length()>0){
       //code goes here
     }
   }catch(e:NumberFormatException){
     e.printStackTrace()
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing an empty string to `Integer.parseInt(input_price_from.text.toString())`.

You should first check if the string is not empty and is an integer before calling `Integer.parseInt(input_price_from.text.toString())`.

You can perform the check for emptyness and the number being an integer by writing some code along these lines:

```
String n = input_price_from.text.toString();
if(n != null) {
    String trimmed = n.trim();
    if(!trimmed.isEmpty() && trimmed.matches("\\d+")) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(n.trim());
        System.out.println(num);
        // ... whatever code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I found it!

the same thing goes for `priceFrom` as well as `priceTo`

```
priceFrom = Integer.parseInt(input_price_from.text.toString())
```

if there is no text then parseInt will try to parse an empty string which throws Runtime Exception.

you can do something like this

```
val text = input_price_from.text.toString.trim()
if (text.isNotEmpty() && text.matches("\\d+")) {
        try {
            priceFrom = text.toInt()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            priceFrom = 0 //default value if the text includes anything 
            //except for the number.
        }
    }
```

Plus you can make your `EditText` with `inputType = number` to enforce used to enter only numbers